# Are package file listings supposed to include only distributed files, or runtime generated files too?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, directory-structure

I've been looking for where some files on my system have come from, such as (for sake of having an example, but question not specific to this) `/etc/udev/hwdb.bin`:

```
$ pacman -Qo /etc/udev/hwdb.bin
error: No package owns /usr/lib/udev/hwdb.bin
```

Then searching, [it seems clear](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/hwdb.html) it's compiled by `systemd-hwdb`, which is itself distributed with `systemd` (and included in its file listing):

```
$ pacman -Qo "$(which systemd-hwdb)"
/usr/bin/systemd-hwdb is owned by systemd 245.5-2
```

I've seen this with several different packages, and at first thought it's simply an omission, and they should be listed - but perhaps it's because they're files generated by an included executable, rather than being distributed with the package itself? Is that correct?

So if a hypothetical package is packaged as a script that merely downloads and installs the 'real' package, the first's file listing would be nothing more than 'installer.sh'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package file listings for Arch Linux include files that are contained in the package, that are installed when the package is installed. They don't include files that the installed application could potentially create on your system.

For instance, the package for the Evolution e-mail program would not list every e-mail that could be downloaded to your system, and a video game package would not list save game files that might be created by the user (both for obvious reasons - they can't be predicted). The file lists include files that are installed and managed by the package manager.

Comment: Understood, thanks. I do think there could be a valuable distinction between user-created or 'optionally' generated files like emails, and compiled schemata or databases that the program *always* creates, though.